# Is there a way to retrieve Metadata dependencies via ANT?

Tags: deployment, metadata-api

Title pretty much says it. Just curious if there is a way to check for metadata dependencies through the Metadata API.

Similar to the feature in change sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea will be to create a managed package and then retrieve that package using the metadata API. Documentation on how to do that is [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/forcemigrationtool_retrieve_packaged.htm). The managed package will tell you the various dependencies. I haven't tried it so I can't give you further details but I thought I would share the idea and see if you can use it and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot know components dependencies using metadatata api.

Using metadata api you can only know failed components details due to absence of dependent component.

This applies to ANT and other tools using the Metadata API.